# Properly scoped transactions in Stored Procs

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, transactions, scope

Suppose I have a stored procedure that manages its own transaction

```
CREATE PROCEDURE theProc
AS
BEGIN

  BEGIN TRANSACTION

-- do some stuff

  IF @ThereIsAProblem
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
  ELSE
    COMMIT TRANSACTION
END
```

If I call this proc from an existing transaction, the proc can ROLLBACK the external transaction.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
EXEC theProc
COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

How do I properly scope the transaction within the stored procedure, so that the stored procedure does not rollback external transactions?

Comment: Watch [this DNR-TV video](http://www.intellectualhedonism.com/2008/06/01/dnrTV113BrentVanderMeideOnTransactionScopesInNET20Part1.aspx), they talk a lot about transaction scoping, though handling it in code vs. sql. hope this helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax to do this probably varies by database.  But in Transact-SQL what you do is check @@TRANCOUNT to see if you are in a transaction.  If you are then you want to create a savepoint, and at the end you can just pass through the end of the function (believing a commit or rollback will happen later) or else rollback to your savepoint.

See Microsoft's documentation on [savepoints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188378.aspx) for more.

Support for savepoints is fairly widespread, but I think the mechanism (assuming there is one) for finding out that you're currently in a transaction will vary quite a bit.

Answer (score 1):

use @@trancount to see if you're already in a transaction when entering